# Kubernetes: PersistentVolumeClaim is invalid: spec: Forbidden

Tags: mysql, windows, kubernetes, kubectl

Following the wordpress/mysql example https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

Mysql-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata:

  name: wordpress-mysql

  labels:

    app: wordpress

spec:

  ports:

    - port: 3306

  selector:

    app: wordpress

    tier: mysql

  clusterIP: None

---

apiVersion: v1

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim

metadata:

  name: mysql-pv-claim

  labels:

    app: wordpress

spec:

  accessModes:

    - ReadWriteOnce

  resources:

    requests:

      storage: 20Gi

---

apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:

  name: wordpress-mysql

  labels:

    app: wordpress

spec:

  selector:

    matchLabels:

      app: wordpress

      tier: mysql

  strategy:

    type: Recreate

  template:

    metadata:

      labels:

        app: wordpress

        tier: mysql

    spec:

      containers:

      - image: mysql:5.6

        name: mysql

        env:

        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

          valueFrom:

            secretKeyRef:

              name: mysql-pass

              key: password

        ports:

        - containerPort: 3306

          name: mysql

        volumeMounts:

        - name: mysql-persistent-storage

          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql

      volumes:

      - name: mysql-persistent-storage

        persistentVolumeClaim:

          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

Worpress-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata:

  name: wordpress

  labels:

    app: wordpress

spec:

  ports:

    - port: 80

  selector:

    app: wordpress

    tier: frontend

  type: LoadBalancer

---

apiVersion: v1

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim

metadata:

  name: wp-pv-claim

  labels:

    app: wordpress

spec:

  accessModes:

    - ReadWriteOnce

  resources:

    requests:

      storage: 20Gi

---

apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:

  name: wordpress

  labels:

    app: wordpress

spec:

  selector:

    matchLabels:

      app: wordpress

      tier: frontend

  strategy:

    type: Recreate

  template:

    metadata:

      labels:

        app: wordpress

        tier: frontend

    spec:

      containers:

      - image: wordpress:4.8-apache

        name: wordpress

        env:

        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST

          value: wordpress-mysql

        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD

          valueFrom:

            secretKeyRef:

              name: mysql-pass

              key: password

        ports:

        - containerPort: 80

          name: wordpress

        volumeMounts:

        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage

          mountPath: /var/www/html

      volumes:

      - name: wordpress-persistent-storage

        persistentVolumeClaim:

          claimName: wp-pv-claim
```

> kubectl apply -k ./

```
service/wordpress created
service/wordpress-mysql created
persistentvolumeclaim/wp-pv-claim created
deployment.apps/wordpress created
deployment.apps/wordpress-mysql created
The PersistentVolumeClaim "mysql-pv-claim" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: spec is immutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims
  core.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec{
        ... // 2 identical fields
        Resources:        {Requests: {s"storage": {i: {...}, s: "20Gi", Format: "BinarySI"}}},
        VolumeName:       "mysql-pv-volume",
-       StorageClassName: &"manual",
+       StorageClassName: nil,
        VolumeMode:       &"Filesystem",
        DataSource:       nil,
        DataSourceRef:    nil,
  }
```

Kubectl client/server version: v1.25.9

Comment: Looks like you already have a pvc with the same name

Comment: Found another mysql PVC created before. resolved. thanks.